# Tomcat some image file response always cache-control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

Tags: java, spring, servlets, cache-control

//////////////////// Configuration information ////////////////

```
Environment :         
    java : oracle 8
    Spring4 xml config
    eclispe version: 2020-06(4.16.0)
    was-server: tomcat 8.5
    servlet: web-app_3_1.xsd version=3.1 
    jsp: 2.1
Sympthoms: some image files are always returned with "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

Our system landing page includes jsp file like below.

```
///////////////////// landing.jsp ///////////////////////////
    <span> <image name="aaa" src="----------------" /> </span>
        <jsp:include pag="/WEB-INF/jsp/usr/common/curation.jsp">
        <jsp:param name="resourceNo" value="21" />
    </jsp:include>
```

When landing page was loaded. I checked the response header in chrome network tab.
the image aaa had Cache-Control: max-age=0 ( this is good because browser does not try network round trip)

But on the images in the inner jsp file(/WEB-INF/jsp/usr/common/curation.jsp)
They are always downloaded on the origin tomcat server.

So I checked the Cash-Control's value...
It was "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate".

But our system did not set any response Cahche-Control header value.

I don't know why tomcat always use cach-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate on that inner jsp images.

So I decided to create Filter that overwrite the Cahche-Control value like below

```
///////////////////////////// web.xml /////////////////////////////////
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>testFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

////////////////////////////// Filter ////////////////////////////////
```

```
pulbic void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletExcetpion{
    resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // 
    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");

}
```

But despite of applying filter, the images in the curation.jsp does not use cache, because they are always returned with no-cache, no-store, re-validate..

[image]
Anybody knows this magical sympthoms...
guide me how do I fix this... I want to use cache only "max-age=0".

thank you in advance

Comment: without webserver like apache, even in eclipse local tomcat server. inner jsp images are returned with no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate.

Comment: I have already checked tomcat default servlet configurations, but there was no extra-configuration about Cache-Control

Comment: The set-cookie header says that you're running this behind AWSALB which is a load balancing proxy of AWS EC2. Look over there. This is at least not a programming problem.

Comment: Thank you BalusC. I will ask AWS teachnical team. Thank you very much. Have a nice day